# Trouble installing hsdev on windows to use SublimeHaskell with SublimeText

Tags: haskell, sublimetext3, cabal, sublime-text-plugin, haskell-platform

I have been trying to install the SublimeHaskell package for SublimeText and every time I open SublimeText I get a popup error message saying:

```
Backend configuration: "Local hsdev"
Incompatible hsdev, detected version 0.0.0.0
Version should be >= 0.3.3.0 and < 0.3.4.0
```

I therefore tried running the command:  `cabal install hsdev` and I get the following error

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cabal install hsdev
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' is 24 days old.
Run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available packages.
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' is 24 days old.
Run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available packages.
Resolving dependencies...
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: hsdev-0.3.3.8 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: template-haskell (dependency of hsdev)
[__1] rejecting: template-haskell-2.16.0.0/installed-2.16.0.0 (conflict: hsdev
=> template-haskell>=2.11.0 && <2.16)
[__1] skipping: template-haskell-2.16.0.0 (has the same characteristics that
caused the previous version to fail: excluded by constraint '>=2.11.0 &&
<2.16' from 'hsdev')
[__1] rejecting: template-haskell-2.15.0.0, template-haskell-2.14.0.0,
template-haskell-2.13.0.0, template-haskell-2.12.0.0,
template-haskell-2.11.1.0, template-haskell-2.11.0.0,
template-haskell-2.10.0.0, template-haskell-2.9.0.0, template-haskell-2.8.0.0,
template-haskell-2.7.0.0, template-haskell-2.6.0.0, template-haskell-2.5.0.0,
template-haskell-2.4.0.1, template-haskell-2.4.0.0, template-haskell-2.3.0.1,
template-haskell-2.3.0.0, template-haskell-2.2.0.0 (constraint from
non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: hsdev, template-haskell)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: ghc-mod, hsdev, hlint,
haskell-src-exts, base, template-haskell
Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.
```

I've tried re-installing cabal and it still won't let me download hsdev (I'm on a windows machine and installed the Haskell Platform using chocolatey), any suggestions?

```
cabal-install version 3.2.0.0
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.2
```

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: it looks like hsdev wasn't installing with latest GHC as far back as 2018: https://github.com/mvoidex/hsdev/issues/91#issuecomment-419731848 and the project doesn't look terribly active to me overall

Comment: https://mpickering.github.io/ide/posts/2020-05-08-state-of-haskell-ide.html looking at this article, hsdev isn't even mentioned as a valid IDE plug-in anymore, so I'd recommend ditching it in favour of a newer plug-in, OR installing an older version using Stack, if you must